# C# to VB.net code conversion. Issue with anonymous New()

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm currently translating the class that comes with [Bundler](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Bundler), part of the framework [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net). The bit I'm currently stuck with is the following:

```
new { media }
```

or

```
new[] { typeof(object) }
```

I'm a VB.net programmer, and I don't really get what is being done here. Creating some sort of a anonymous parameter?

**PS:** It might be worth noting the context in which this is happening: Both of those constructions are being passed as parameters to functions.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

Ok, now (I think) I understand what the code does, but I'm still helpless regarding the vb.net equivalent code for those snippets, could you lend me a hand?

Comment: The first snippet is creating an instance of an anonymous type with a single property. The second snippet is creating a single-element array of type `Type[]`. The compiler is inferring the array type.

Comment: Wow, I've been Skeeted (there, I said it). Second, see the edit on the question please ;)

Comment: Why are you translating a command-line tool you can (should) use as-is? If you want to make modifications you should make them in the tool's language, unless you want to get stuck with old code the next time Bundler changes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's not a command line (as far as I know). I use only the Bundler part downloaded through NuGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two code snippets you posted show separate language features:

```
new { media }
```

This one shows how you instantiate anonymous type instance. You can read more about anonymous types here: [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). You can read about anonymous types in VB.NET here: [Anonymous Types (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx).

For your type equivalent VB.NET code would be:

```
New With { Key .media = media }
```

`Key` makes property in anonymous type set-only and makes equality comparison on that type check that property to determine if entire object is equal. In C# all anonymous type property are *key* properties by default, and you can't make them mutable.

Second one:

```
new [] { typeof(object) }
```

This one creates implicitly typed `Type[]` array.

You can create similar array in VB.NET with following syntax:

```
{ GetType(object) }
```

Read [How to: Initialize an Array Variable in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx) for more details.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for providing all this useful information.

Answer (score 1):

The `new { foo = bar }` syntax in C# instantiates an anonymous type.

`new[]` creates an implicitly-typed array, unlike anonymous types it is a language-shorthand and has no semantic implications (unless it's an implicitly-typed array of anonymous types).

The VB equivalent is described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

```
New With { Key media }
```

VB.NET has the concept of "Key properties" - which are readonly and participate in equality comparisons. in C# all properties of anonymous types are considered key properties.

Comment: That's not quite equivalent - you'd want to make it a `Key` property.